# Column Name in Stored Procedure Parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Guys i  have a stored procedure which return count based on the select query. My question is that i want to make the procedure generic i.e if i pass a column name to the stored procedure parameter then it should return the result depending on the data in that column name.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetChartValue] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @grade char(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Select COUNT(*) from feedback where 0 in (@grade)
    Select COUNT(*) from feedback where 1 in (@grade)
    Select COUNT(*) from feedback where 2 in (@grade)
    Select COUNT(*) from feedback where 3 in (@grade)
    Select COUNT(*) from feedback where 4 in (@grade)
    Select COUNT(*) from feedback where 5 in (@grade)

END
```

I did google but didnt got a proper solution for this. Can anyone suggest be how to achieve it . If any error in stored procedure please do point out.

Comment: please try `...where columnName in (@grade)` just put one line remove all.
what you are sending in @grade

Comment: Why do not know which column somebody might want? If you proceed down this path you will have to use dynamic sql. Make sure you wrap the column name with QUOTENAME to help prevent sql injection.

Comment: What do you put in @@grade ? A fieldname ? A value to search in a field ?  What do the values 0..5 stand for ?    if you put 5 in @@grade this procedure will return a count of all records from feedback, in all other cases it will return 0 (because only the last select will be returned)

Comment: You can't use variables as column names. To create something like that you'll need to use dynamic SQL

Comment: @GuidoG actually the procedure will return multiple result sets. One for each query. But of course there are many other reasons this won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this would be using sp_executesql.
It will do the job but I think that you also loose any benefits of stored procedures

```
create procedure spGetChartValue (@FieldName nvarchar(50), @Value nvarchar(50) as
begin
    set nocount on

    declare @sql nvarchar(1000) = 'select count(1) from Feedback where ' + quotename(@fieldname) + ' = ' + quotename(@grade, '''')
    exec sp_executesql @sql

end
```

from your last comment I think you are looking for something like this ?

```
create procedure spGetChartValue (@Grade nvarchar(50)) as
begin
    set nocount on

    declare @sql nvarchar(1000)

    set @sql = 'select '
    set @sql = @sql + '(select count(1) from Feedback where ' + quotename(@Grade) + ' = 0) as grade_0, '     
    set @sql = @sql + '(select count(1) from Feedback where ' + quotename(@Grade) + ' = 1) as grade_1, '     
    set @sql = @sql + '(select count(1) from Feedback where ' + quotename(@Grade) + ' = 2) as grade_2 '     
    -- and so on...

    exec sp_executesql @sql
end;
```

Comment: Added quotename to my answer to make it safe against sql injection

Comment: i tried it but it didnt worked for me ..........
What i want is i have 6 columns in which there are int values from 0-5 in each of the tables 
Each select statement gives me the count of 0,1,2,3,4,5 in that particular column....... I want to make the stored procedure generic so that if i pass the column name in that it will give me the result related to that particular column ........ 
My question is that is it possible ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your comment.  The answer I (and Sean) gave you explains how you can execute a query in a stored procedure with a columnname as parameter.  It should now be possible for you to build your queries in the stored procedure to do what you want.   I cannot help you with that queries because it is not clear to me what you are trying to do.  Maybe you can edit your question to make more clear what you want this stored procedure to do ?

Comment: @Aditya Pewekar: edited my answer to what I think you are looking for. If this is not what you want then please edit your question to make more clear for us what you are looking for

Comment: thanks for that second one ....... thats wat i was exaclty looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you use the dynamic sql approach it should be more like this to prevent sql injection.

```
create procedure spGetChartValue 
(
    @FieldName nvarchar(50)
    , @Value nvarchar(50)
) as
begin
    set nocount on

    declare @sql nvarchar(1000) = 'select count(1) from feedback where ' + QUOTENAME(@FieldName) + ' = @value' 
    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@Value nvarchar(50)', @Value

end
```

Comment: i tried it but it didnt worked for me ..........
What i want is i have 6 columns in which there are int values from 0-5 in each of the tables 
Each select statement gives me the count of 0,1,2,3,4,5 in that particular column....... I want to make the stored procedure generic so that if i pass the column name in that it will give me the result related to that particular column ........ 
My question is that is it possible ?

Comment: It is likely possible but your comment doesn't make any sense. Unless you are saying you want 6 columns, each of which gives you the count of rows where the value of 0,1, etc appears. That is just awful design but it is possible. You would have to run a query for each where predicate to do this. Not only is it ugly it just seems very odd.